# C++ memset / memcpy / strcpy implementation performance

Tags: c++, performance

In C++, I have made a basic memset / memcpy / strcpy implementation, yet I am worried that they are slower than the STL equivalent, as they are probably made in assembly, which I do not know. Is there any way of making these quicker, still using C++?

```
#define BYTE unsigned char

typedef BYTE byte;

void *__memset(void *_Dst, int _Val, UINT _Size)
{
    BYTE *buf = (BYTE *)_Dst;
    while (_Size--)
    {
        *buf++ = (BYTE)_Val;
    }
    return _Dst;
}

void *__memcpy(void *_Dst, const void *_Src, UINT _Size)
{
    BYTE *buf = (BYTE *)_Dst;
    BYTE *__Src = (BYTE *)_Src;
    while (_Size--)
    {
        *buf++ = *__Src++;
    }
    return _Dst;
}

char *__strcpy(char *_Dst, const char *_Src)
{
    while ((*_Dst++ = *_Src++) != '\0');
    return _Dst;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These are [Runtime library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library) functions, not STL (template library) functions.

The run-time library is arguably part of the language (so you can use the built-in library functions and still be "using C++").

It's possible that your compiler is able to generate these as [intrinsic functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=intrinsic+strcpy).

Things you can try to make your functions faster:

- Use a compiler with a better optimizer
- Copy 4 or 8 bytes at a time
- If the buffers aren't aligned on a 4- or 8-byte boundary, copy 1 byte at a time until you come to a boundary alignment, and then copy 4 or 8 bytes at a time

Comment: See implementation and discussion here: http://www.noxeos.com/2013/08/06/code-optimisations/

Answer (score 2):

You can test for yourself if your implementation is faster or slower than the "official" one: Simply write a test program that allocates large chunks of memory and then make a number of calls to your implementation and take the time. Then, rewrite your program to use the corresponding STL functions and repeat the time taking.

About the performance, I would assume that it is faster to operate on data types as large as the word size of your architecture (64 bit, maybe only 32 bit) instead of 8 bit only (=byte aka char). The data type "unsigned integer" should do the trick.